# Identity API Scope Approval UI preventing OAuth Verification

Tags: google-chrome, google-oauth

I have a chrome extension I am trying to go through OAuth verification with. The requirement is that I do a screen recording displaying the URL with the Client ID in it. When going through authentication an application which appears to be part of the Chrome package called Identity API Scope Approval UI pops up for the authentication. The OAuth Verification team continues to tell me I need to submit with a URL bar. How do I get the URL back?

This line of code is requesting the token.

```
chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ interactive: true }, function (token) {})
```

[image: Identity API Scope Approval UI]

Comment: I think they want the url bar in you browser window they need to see where that screen is coming from.   It should open in the Users default browser window displaying to the user the URL that it is hitting.

Comment: There is no ClientID as requested in the browser window. it's a Google File link.

Comment: Then your doing it wrong the Google authentication screen you are showing should be opening in the Web browser then need to see the URL bar in the web browser.

Comment: This code has worked on multiple extensions previously. Why is it now pulling up this other application? What method would be more appropriate?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: @vijay  the solution was to use the Developer tools in fill screen mode to display the url in the top of the bar.

Answer (score 0):

The Identity API Scope Approval UI can be right clicked and the url seen at the top. Maximize the window and you should be able to get a view of the client ID. I also have displayed the HTML with the client ID for good measure.

Comment: I tied to right-click it, and there was no effect. Looks like I have to do it on a Mac...